# How should I insulate and block moisture in a floor over a crawl space?

Tags: insulation, subfloor, vapor-barrier

Summary

- Planning to replace carpet in walk in closet. Pulled up padding and found 5/8" partcleboard as only subfloor. Ripped that out and have some 23/32 gp dryguard osb going in.
- Under the subfloor, there was old insulation with facing on both sides.
- There was some yellow/white mold on the pine boards under the insulation in some spots. It smells damp/musty, and the old insulation looked like it might have been moldy in some spots.
- On the left is my uninsulated garage. straight ahead is outside. right side is outside, and part of a bedroom. also on the right is the basement, which may be where the musty smell is coming from. there's a cinder block wall on the right side of the dirt and stuff. behind me is a mudroom which is insulated, but heating/cooling in there.

So I'm just trying to figure out.. Do I need a vapor barrier somewhere here? When I replace the insulation, what kind should I use? Faced, unfaced, etc. Any other suggestions? I feel like this is hard to read and mess, but I'm not sure how to make it better. I appreciate any input.

I plan to fix up the wiring that you can see too, but that's last.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your drawing. The top bold, black line is your new 3/4" floor sheathing? Then what's the bottom bold, black line? There's two different elevations of framing? I don't see anything like that in the picture.

Comment: Sounds like the particle board _wasn't_ the only subfloor. Your subfloor was the particle board over foam over pine boards. Is that right? It wasn't clear that the insulation was rigid and not fiberglass.